# using colorTransformer to make color fading out effect

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a good sample how to make a color "fading out" demo effect, something like this:

```
colorTransformer.redMultiplier = colorTransformer.redMultiplier -.2 ;
colorTransformer.greenMultiplier = colorTransformer.greenMultiplier -.2 ;
colorTransformer.blueMultiplier = colorTransformer.blueMultiplier  -.2 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Daniel : gtween, tweener and all the others does the work with *ease*.

If you want to custimize it you can get great use of getters and setters though (this is often used for more complex situations but may be interesting) :

```
private var _brightness:Number = 1;

public function set brightness(value:Number):void
{
    _brightness = value
    this.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(value,value,value);
}

public function get brightness():Number
{
    return _brightness;
}
```

**Examples :**

Simple :

`brightness = 0;`

Random linear :

`brightness -= Math.random() * .02;`

Interactive and eased :

`brightness += ((stage.mouseY / stage.stageHeight)-brightness) * .9;`

etc.

Comment: I am trying to adjust color of TextField() - but there is no .brightness?

Comment: To use it like explained above, you need to extend the TextField class adding the brightness getter/setter.